# django-tastypie hydrate m2m with through table

Tags: tastypie

I am trying to save a resource related through a `ToMany` and some complicated data processing when it created and want to figure out the best way to refactor my giant, kludgy obj_create into something that makes sense within the paradigm of tastypie.

At the moment,  my `obj_create` looks something like this:

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    sid = transaction.savepoint()
    try:
        data = self.deserialize(bundle.request, bundle.request.body)
        related_data = data.pop('related')
        ## get_or_create the related objects by processing the data passed
        related_objs = self.create_related_objs(related_data)

        ## Create the object the above are related to
        obj = self._meta.object_class.objects.create(**data)  # this has been cleaned of non-object keys
        for (order, related) in enumerate(related_objs):
            ObjRelation.objects.create(obj=obj, related=related, order=order)
    except:
        transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
        raise Badrequest("you fail it")
    bundle.obj = obj
    bundle.data = data
    transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
    return bundle
```

So this is a rather simplified version of what I'm doing.  I believe that it would be better to move the related saving to a subclass of `fields.ToManyField`, but I cannot see what methods I would need to over-ride.  Or would it be better to put it into `hydrate_related`?